# Install patch SUPEE-11086

Tags: magento-1.9, patches

Magento has just released the patch [SUPEE-11086](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-11086) i am using Magento Version 1.9.2.2

I have scan my site in https://magereport.com it is not showing the `SUPEE-11086` patch details.

i have also checked with other projects with different version too. do i still need to install the patch?

Comment: Have you tried with Magento Security Scan?https://magento.com/security Find the magento security scan tool link here

Comment: is there any other way?

Comment: You can also check if the patch has been applied by checking app/etc/applied.patches.list or do manually check from the patch file if the specified changes are done in the code

Comment: @RajMohanR Thank You :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check it either via Magento official security scan tool [magento.com/security](http://magento.com/security)

When patches have applied a file named `applied.patches.list` is added in the `app/etc/` directory or straight away check the code specified in the patch file to check if the patch has been applied to confirm it. I have also used some third party scan tools to check if the patch is applied but they are not right all the time.
Please find the patch for your version from Magento Resources. Move the patch file into your Magento root directory. If your patch file has .sh extension `sh PATCH_SUPEE-11086_CE_1.5.0.0_v1.sh`, if it has .patch extension `patch -p0 < PRODSECBUG-2198-2.2-CE.composer-2019-03-27-06-12-19.patch`

Comment: also can you write the steps to install patch?